# How do I print the answer to an equation in C?

Tags: c

I'd like for the program to solve my equation yet sadly it doesn't. Additionally, I'd want for it to print an answer depending on the value of x that I input in the equation. Please let me know how I would be able to print the answer or how I can program it so that the equation gives me an answer that I can then print.

```
/* Preprocessor directives */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Main program */
void main ()
{
    /*
        variable declaration section comments

    l:              length value
    q:              value of q
    ei:             value of ei
    s:              l devided by 2 since 0 < x < l/2
    b:              the length l (thus, 20)
    z:              0
    first_equation: The first equation pertaining to 0 < x < l/2
    second_equation:The second equation pertaining to l/2 < x < l
*/

double x, first_equation, second_equation, l, q, ei, s, b, z;

l = 20.0;
q = 4000.0;
ei = 1.2 * (pow(10.0, 8.0));
s = l / 2.0;
b = l;
z = 0.0;

printf ("please enter the x-value\n");
scanf ("%lf", &x);

/* Deflection equations */
first_equation = ((q * x) / (384.0 * ei)) * ((9 * (pow(l, 3.0))) - (24.0 * l      * (pow(x, 2.0))) + (16 * (pow(x, 3.0))));
second_equation = ((q * l) / (384.0 * ei)) * ((8 * (pow(x, 3.0))) -     (24.0 *       l * (pow(x, 2.0))) + (17 * (pow(l, 2.0)) * x) - (pow(l, 3.0))); 

    /* Determining what equation to use */
    if (x >= z && x <= s)
        printf ("\n first_equation\n\n");
    else if (x > s && x <= b)
        printf ("\n second_equation\n\n", second_equation);
    else if (x < 0 || x > b)
        printf ("\n invalid location\n\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: As it is, the question only gives half the data. What is the mathematical formulation of the equations? And, most importantly, what makes you think that the "equation isn't solved" - what doesn't meet your expectations? Be specific.

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`?

Comment: So essentially I would want the answer to first_equation and second_equation given the values and whatever x is to be printed, or at least make it so that it solves it for me and then I would make it so it corresponded to the right values.

Comment: printf( "first %lf", first_equation ); See the online documentation for printf.

Answer (score 3):

This...

```
printf ("\n second_equation\n\n", second_equation);
```

... does not print the `second_equation` variable: it provides it as an argument to `printf`, but `printf` only uses extra arguments as directed by `%f` or other conversion instructions embedded in the text provided as the first argument.  You could write:

```
printf ("\n second_equation %f\n\n", second_equation);
```

You may want to do something similar for `first_equation`.

Alternatively [when I answered the question was tagged C++] you could use C++ I/O routines (`scanf` and `printf` are from the C library, and have a number of disadvantages, the most obvious here being that you have to remember funny letter codes like "lf" matching your data types)...

```
#include <iostream>
```

...at the very top of your file, then in your function write...

```
std::cout << "\n second_equation " << second_equation << "\n\n";
```

You could also use C++ I/O for input, replacing `scanf` with...

```
if (!(std::cin >> x))
{
    std::cerr << "you didn't enter a valid number\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really unclear; but going by your question, you seem to want to be able to print your answer. In that case, here is the proper syntax

```
printf ("Answer: %d \n", yourAnswer); //if 'yourAnswer' is decimal or number
```

To use one of your code snippets, you'll have this:

```
printf ("\n second_equation: %d\n", second_equation);
```